# Deploy Qt App using Postgresql

Tags: c++, qt, postgresql, dll

I want to deploy my desktop app built using Qt 5.4.0 MinGw and PostgreSQL 9.4 as database, to another computer, here is the file in my executable folder:

```
icudt53.dll
icuin53.dll           
icuuc53.dll           
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libintl-8.dll         
libstdc++-6.dll       
libwinpthread-1.dll
Qt5Core.dll           
Qt5Gui.dll
Qt5PrintSupport.dll   
Qt5Script.dll         
Qt5Sql.dll
Qt5Widgets.dll        
Qt5Xml.dll
```

the problem is I got this error: Driver not loaded when connecting to the database. I have tried to copy the folder plugins\sqldrivers to my app dir but i still got the same error.

Comment: Do you build project at release mode? Try to copy only `qsqlpsql.dll` (or `qsqlpsqld.dll` if build in debug mode), not folder with plugins at all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy `\plugins\sqldrivers` or just `\sqldrivers`? It should be just `\sqldrivers` in the application installation directory.